# Color grade system A,B,C,D,F

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design, color-scheme, ux-designer

Hhhh, in my new porject I have color grade system that looks like this, but my `A(A-,A+)` and `B(..)` is very similar(color) and they are very difficult to distinguish. Any ideas how to do it *nicely ?

*- I need a basic palette of colors, so that people can understand them at the level of instincts, so I can not enter the 4th color (for example `blue`)

[image]

Comment: Can I point out that B is really lacking contrast? And C as well a little bit? As a side-note, I wonder what kind of cultural expectations these colours will convey? Is B- always acceptable? Is C+ always mediocre? Or are there different standards of appreciation depending on the school/course/culture?

Comment: With regards to what *Steve DL* said about if C+ is always mediocre etc
Perhaps making it a gradient transition instead of a sharp colour change could perhaps fix that

Comment: Simply asking for a palette of colours is more a graphic design issue, and off topic.  But if you rephrase it to ask specifically how to make the ratings system distinct (which would possibly include colours), it would be on topic.  So until then I'm putting this on hold.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold pending improvement in the question.